# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_Callback] Call must be a function......when trying to run a collection in Postman from a CSV file

Tags: csv, postman, typeerror

Trying to load values for a collection from a CSV file but getting the error above.

Worked perfectly fine before but now gives the error message....has something changed with Postman in the last few days??? or am I missing something obvious

Comment: For starters, you could show WHAT you are actually trying to do ... and where the error happens

Comment: I'm trying to "Run" a collection in Postman. Using the select file option to pick up the CSV file from my folder....I select the file and then get the error. It's not an issue with the request...it's that load mechanism, which was working fine until this week....for me and others

Comment: Solved by downloading desktop version of Postman....in case anyone else has the same issue. Believe there have been some changes which stopped may have impacted on the on-line version file load :)